# Maximize production rate - probability and expectation

Tags: probability, expectation

A factory consists of N machines that produce products at a rate of 1 per hour.
Each machine randomly chooses an hour to reset itself for maintenance, during that time the entire factory is shut down. What is the optimal N to maximize production rate?

Everything is discrete to full hour intervals, so for example if there are 2 machines, then there is 1/24 chance of collision in reset time, in which case the total production is going to be $2*23 = 46$ products. Otherwise, there will be 2 shut-downs and a total of $2*22 = 44$ products. So the expectation for N=2 will be $$E(2)=46\cdot\frac{1}{24}+44\cdot\frac{23}{24}$$

I want to find the probability function for k shut-downs given N machines and then calculate $$E(N)=\sum_{k=1}^{23}f(k,N)\cdot P(k|N)$$ where $f(k,N) = N\cdot(24-k)$ is the number of products for N machines and k shut-downs.
Then I'll differentiate dN and finish the rest.

But I can't find $P$... How should I calculate it? Or is there a more elegant way to get E, say using its properties such as linearity?
Thanks!

Comment: First, your notation is a bit off: $E(2)$? I know what you mean though. The probabilities will include combinations of machine shutdowns coinciding or not, and this should be similar to binomial coefficients. Try to do the 3 machine case, and then 4 machine case. I think you can since you worked out the 2 case. Then maybe you will see the generalization. Intuitively as N gets large production guess to zero since the factory will just be shutdown constantly.

Answer (score 1):

The probability that production occurs in a given hour is

$$
\left(\frac{23}{24}\right)^N\;.
$$

Thus by linearity of expectation the expected product is

$$
24N\left(\frac{23}{24}\right)^N\;.
$$

To get the distribution of the number $k$ of shutdowns, note that this is equivalent to counting the number of strings of length $N$ over an alphabet of $24$ letters that use exactly $k$ different letters. There are $\binom{24}k$ ways to choose the $k$ hours, and by inclusion-exclusion there are

$$
\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom kj(k-j)^N
$$

ways for the $N$ machines to shut all of them down at least once, so the probability for exactly $k$ shutdowns is

$$
{24}^{-N}\binom{24}k\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^j\binom kj(k-j)^N\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks, that's a very elegant solution. I still wonder how to generate the general probability function though. But maybe for another time...

Comment: @Yoni: I added the distribution for the number of shutdowns.